# Event Sourcing "meta-stream" containing name, create, delete etc

Tags: event-sourcing

In a system I'm working on, we have a bunch of "processes".
Each process can be created, renamed, (soft)deleted.
When creating a process, a name must be provided before we are allowed to continue.

We are considering having a "meta-stream", containing instances of the following events:

- Create {name, id}
- Delete {id}
- Rename {name, id}

As well as another stream containing events that represents the internal state of the process.

Pros:

- If we don't do this, we'd have to add an "Initialize {name}"-command to the non-meta process stream. We'd have to enforce the invariant that this initialize-command is supposed to come first in each and every process' stream.

Cons:

- The true state of the process is split up between two different streams, we need to go to one stream to check whether it exists, and then to another stream to get its state. Might lead to inconsistencies.

Any reflections on this?

Comment: You mentioned having two streams, but I don't think I understand why you are looking to use that approach. It might make sense to identify the reasons for splitting the streams. Without that, I am imagining that you want to avoid having a stream that is mostly internal bookkeeping vs configuration. What is the lifetime of a process? Do you run multiple instances of one? Should you perhaps consider modeling the "running" of a process as a domain concept, perhaps as an Aggregate. I'm not comfortable suggesting one or the other option without these details.

Comment: The "processes" have a long lifetime, they are created/deleted by users. I understand now how the lack of  context makes this sound like a technical thing, but a process is a domain concept.

As such, they are not runnable, rather think of them as "documents", "working areas" or a similar concept.

Comment: Why are you considering two streams? I apologize if I missed it, but I am not seeing the reasoning behind doing so.